# Can't open camera after activity is closed

Tags: android, background, android-camera2

I'm developing an app that takes pictures frequently with no relate to any activity. It works fine while there is a running activity, but as soon as I close the activity, the app can't open the camera using the command `camera.open(0);`.

I've tried to use window manager and [hidden-camera](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera) library which both didn't work for me.

Do you have any idea how to open a camera while there is no activity alive?

Answer (score 0):

Although your concern got downvoted, but if you are a new to Android development the explanation is just for an idea that if you close your activity then an activity instance will be finished.

In application you can do any operation in an activity until the activity instance is alive.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't explain it right. I meant that I was running a service (I've tried both service and job service), after I closed the activity they crashed with it, but when the system executed them once again (while the activity is still closed) I couldn't open the camera.